# Why changing an input type number with the mousewheel doesn't trigger an onchange event

Tags: blazor, blazor-hybrid

I have a table with inputs of type number.
I have added onmousewheel="" to the inputs parameters.
The mouse wheel is now changing the values in the inputs, but no onchange event is triggered.

The solution I'm using right now to retreive the new value when modified with the mouse wheel is Javascript interop

But I wonder if there is not a simpler solution.

Maybe someone has an idea?

Comment: `onchange` event is triggered when the input loses focus. Instead, listen for the `oninput` event.

Answer (score 0):

The demo page below shows how to do updates on `oninput`.  It's simple with a standard `input`, but if you're using `InputNumber` you'll need to create a custom version of `InputNumber`.

Here's the demo page:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<div class="mb-3">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" @bind=value @bind:event="oninput"/>
</div>

<div class="mb-3">
    <MyInputNumber class="form-control" type="number" @bind-Value=value/>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white">
    <pre>Value : @this.value</pre>
</div>


@code {
    private int? value;
}
```

And `MyInputNumber`.

```cs
@inherits InputNumber<TValue>
@typeparam TValue

<input step="@GetStepAttributeValue()" 
    @attributes=this.AdditionalAttributes
    type="number"
    class="@this.CssClass"
    @bind="@this.CurrentValueAsString"
    @bind:event="@_bindEvent"
    @ref=this.Element
    />

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool UpdateOnInput { get; set; }

    private string _bindEvent => UpdateOnInput ? "oninput" :  "onchange";

    private static string GetStepAttributeValue()
    {
        // Unwrap Nullable<T>, because InputBase already deals with the Nullable aspect
        // of it for us. We will only get asked to parse the T for nonempty inputs.
        var targetType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TValue)) ?? typeof(TValue);
        if (targetType == typeof(int) ||
            targetType == typeof(long) ||
            targetType == typeof(short) ||
            targetType == typeof(float) ||
            targetType == typeof(double) ||
            targetType == typeof(decimal))
        {
            return "any";
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"The type '{targetType}' is not a supported numeric type.");
        }
    }
}
```